# NativeScript 8 not compiling SCSS to CSS

Tags: css, webpack, sass, nativescript

In my project, I have two scss empty login component files.

If the component loads the CSS:

```
 styleUrls: ["./login-common.css", "./login.css"]
```

when I run `ns run ios` the compiler would throw a CSS not found error.

If I change it to SCSS

```
styleUrls: ["./login-common.scss", "./login.scss"]
```

I don't have any errors but the login screen on the simulator is blank

If I comment the styleUrls line, the login screen would be rendered.

I think I should use the .css version, and probably add/remove some dependency and probably change some config files.  Any idea?

My package.json :

```
"devDependencies": {
"@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.2.7",
"@nativescript/ios": "8.0.0",
"@nativescript/types": "~8.0.0",
"@nativescript/webpack": "beta",
"@ngtools/webpack": "~11.2.6",
"sass-loader": "^12.1.0",
"typescript": "~4.0.0",
"webpack": "^5.49.0"
```

},

My webpack.config.js:

```
const webpack = require("@nativescript/webpack");

module.exports = (env) => {
    webpack.init(env);

  webpack.chainWebpack(config => {
    config.module
      .rule('scss')
      .use('sass-loader')
      .options({ sassOptions: { indentedSyntax: false } })
  })
    return webpack.resolveConfig();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run

```
npm i sass
```

That will install the sass interpreter.

And add a test to your webpack config

```
config.module
        .rule('scss')
        .test( /\.s[ac]ss$/i)
        .use(
              // Compiles Sass to CSS
              "sass-loader"
        )
```

Comment: Thanks! But sadly the problem remains, whether .css files not found , or white screen if I point to .scss

Comment: I updated my answer. You may need to delete your platform folder before running again, too.

Comment: Updated the config. Deleted the folder. Same result either pointing to css or scss

Comment: Sorry, I wasn’t able to help. Sometimes what I will do when I’m stuck is to spin up an angular app from the command line and look at the webpack and other configs. Ns create myNgApp —ts —ng